# What does this emacs-lisp code do?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I am very confused about what the function "do-something" does. Maybe I can replace it with another name.

```el
(defun do-something (m &optional n)
  (let* ((count (if (null n) 20 n))
         (bound (* count m)))
    (loop for i from 0 below m
          do (princ "[ ")
          (loop for j from (+ (- bound) i) to (+ bound i) by m
                do (princ j)
                (princ " "))
          (princ "]\n"))))
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace it?  How will that help you?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it on emacs by cut'n'paste to buffer and run C-x C-e (eval-last-sexp)

```
(do-something 10 10)
[ -100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 ]
[ -99 -89 -79 -69 -59 -49 -39 -29 -19 -9 1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 101 ]
[ -98 -88 -78 -68 -58 -48 -38 -28 -18 -8 2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 102 ]
[ -97 -87 -77 -67 -57 -47 -37 -27 -17 -7 3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93 103 ]
[ -96 -86 -76 -66 -56 -46 -36 -26 -16 -6 4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 104 ]
[ -95 -85 -75 -65 -55 -45 -35 -25 -15 -5 5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 105 ]
[ -94 -84 -74 -64 -54 -44 -34 -24 -14 -4 6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 106 ]
[ -93 -83 -73 -63 -53 -43 -33 -23 -13 -3 7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97 107 ]
[ -92 -82 -72 -62 -52 -42 -32 -22 -12 -2 8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98 108 ]
[ -91 -81 -71 -61 -51 -41 -31 -21 -11 -1 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99 109 ]
```

As you see, it prints 2 dimensional array with some form.